# pass bigdecimal numbers in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to pass value to a method using big decimal number but my program shows compiler errors.

```
package com.khalidFarik;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checknumbersinDecimals(12.3,12.2);
    }

    public static void checknumbersinDecimals(BigDecimal payment1,BigDecimal payment2){
        payment1 = new BigDecimal("1230.23");
        payment2 = new BigDecimal("1230.23");
        BigDecimal number3= payment1.subtract(payment2);
        System.out.println(number3.toString());
    }
}
```

How can I pass the big decimal number to my method `checknumbersinDecimals()` in the main method?

Comment: You can't pass doubles instead of `BigDecimal` in your method. You need to use the appropriate [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double))

Comment: @gtgaxiola, the approapriate constructor would actually be taking a `String` to avoid floating point roundup errors (`12.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125` / `12.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875`) before the `BigDecimal` is created.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Right so, even the documentation of the BigDecimal(double val) specifies it. Yet I was going for `technical-no-compiler-error-correctness` not `pedantic correctness`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You really want to include the error messages into your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method accepts `BigDecimal` as args, but you are passing `12.3,12.2` - which are `double` and not `BigDecimal`.

You pass `BigDecimal` objects as param instead of `double` as follows:

```
checknumbersinDecimals(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(12.3)),new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(12.2)));
```

**Note**: use [BigDecimal(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)) constructor instead of [BigDecimal(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) constructor as by using the latter, you could lose precision. The caution as rightly mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)):

> - The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>     might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>     BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>     a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>     0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>     matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>     that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>     0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> - The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates
>     a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect.
>     Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be
>     used in preference to this one.
> - When a double must be used as a source
>     for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact
>     conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the double
>     to a String using the Double.toString(double) method and then using
>     the BigDecimal(String) constructor. To get that result, use the static
>     valueOf(double) method.

Comment: You should also recommend that the constructor taking a String as the argument be used.  You can lose precision by creating a BigDecimal from a double - see [comments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) in the constructor accepting a double for reference.

Comment: thancs for your answer i have tried you have said you and Ashish Singh but it gives me as result :-0.10000000000000008881784197001252323389

Comment: Dont use the ctor that takes double literals. Use the one that parses string!

Comment: @KhalidFarik update the answer. Use the String constructor. Pass `String.valueOf(12.3)` & `String.valueOf(12.2)` instead

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write "12.3" and "12.2" instead?

Comment: thancs all of you for the answers esdpecialy to Pankaj Singhal i have tried what he have said and it works fine thancs

Answer (score 1):

Passing `BigDecimal` object to a method is similar to passing any other `Object` reference. Create a new Object of BigDecimal and pass it as a reference. You can use below syntax

`checknumbersinDecimals(new BigDecimal(12.3),new BigDecimal(12.2));`

`12.3` represents a `double` value. Passing it as a constructor value for `new BigDecimal(12.3)` creates a `BigDecimal` reference for it

Comment: here is my methode edited     checknumbersinDecimals(new BigDecimal(3.4),new BigDecimal(3.5)); but it gives me as result :-0.10000000000000008881784197001252323389

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` is a recommendation to use rather than the constructor `new BigDecimal()`, which gives you exactly the value you pass in.

```
checknumbersinDecimals(BigDecimal.valueOf(12.3), BigDecimal.valueOf(12.2));
```